# How to make image half visible?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following question. How to make image half visible with
[image]CSS?

It should look like that:

[image]

When I'm moving the image to the right with margin-right 100% for example, there is a horizontal scroll, but how to make image split?

```
.logo{
  opacity: 0.03;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -70%;
  margin-left: 90%;
  
}
```

Comment: The solution depends on the existing CSS code. Can you include the code you've made so far?

Comment: You want to make it half on the left or on the right side?  And it should be under the text or beside the text?

Comment: image should be split on the right side of the screen

Comment: Could you share your HTML? Is this image just the React logo or is the logo plus the dark-blue background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what you did with margin-right 100%; but you will also have to specify overflow-X: hidden; on the body or the parent container.

But there is probably a much more practical way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try use the transform property; reminde to set overflow-x: 0, on parent container.

```
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.logo img{
  z-index:-1;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top: 25vh;
  transform: translatex(50%);
  opacity:0.25;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by setting the right: to negative values and position: absolute.

```
.logo-image {
position: absolute;
top: 160px;
right: -124px;
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
}
```